# gulp-angular-templatecache wrong module name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, hottowel, angular-templatecache

I'm having serious problems getting `gulp-angular-templatecache` to work nicely within my app. I'm using the HotTowel yeomen generator and I modified it a little bit, but I can't seem to get my template cache to use a different module name. Here's the relevant gulpfile code:

```
gulp.task('templatecache', ['clean-code'], function() {
    log('Creating an AngularJS $templateCache');

    return gulp
        .src(config.htmltemplates)
        .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.bytediff.start()))
        .pipe($.minifyHtml({empty: true}))
        .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.bytediff.stop(bytediffFormatter)))
        .pipe($.angularTemplatecache(
            'templates.js',
            {
                module: 'app.templates',
                standalone: true,
                root: 'app/',
                moduleSystem: 'IIFE'
            }
        ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
});
```

The original HotTowel gulpfile had `{module: 'app.core', standalone: false, root: 'app/'}` as the options. Every time I run the build process, my stupid templates.js file looks like this:
`angular.module("app.core").run(["$templateCache"....`

I've tried so many things to change it, but it never goes to `app.templates`. Any ideas?

Comment: its in here: config.htmltemplates

Comment: config.htmltemplates only points to all of my HTML files in my app. It would be `gulp.src('./src/client/app/**/*.html')`. The gulp task is minifying all of those files, then running them through `gulp-angular-templatecache`, so I don't see how that would affect the module that's being defined.

Comment: this is going to sound silly, but have you checked that your gulpfile is actually being executed? Because there's no particular anything that would cause it to default to `app.core` - the default module in the gulp library is actually `templates`.

Comment: Yup! Checked that using the `transformUrl` option and just `console.log`ing every template URL that I get from the gulp task - all of my directive/component template URLs are being printed correctly.